# Инфоблок, у которого несколько свойств привязаны к одному

Tags: битрикс

Каким образом можно оперируя свойствами инфоблока, сделать так:
Создается элемент, допустим с названием "Группа 1". Далее ему задается свойство, например "Участник1", у которого в свою очередь есть еще атрибуты, например (Дата рождения, Фамилия, Имя, Отчество), затем добавляется еще один "Участник2", у которого тоже этот набор атрибутов и т.д. Не пойму как это можно сделать, на данный момент сделано как отдельными элементами, но это не удобно, нужно чтобы в одном элементе было несколько "Участников" со своими свойствами. Как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью одного инфоблока реализовать такое не получится. На данный момент исходя из условия задачи я вижу вариант с двумя инфоблоками.

1. Создаем инфоблок "Группы" и инфоблок "Участники".
2. Инфоблоку "Участники" прописываем нужные свойства (Дата рождения, ФИО, и т.д.).
3. В инфоблоке "Группы" создаем множественное свойство "Участники группы" типа "Привязка к элементу инфоблока" и указываем привязку к инфоблоку "Участники".
4. Теперь в элемент "Группа1" вы можете добавлять сколько нужно участников из инфоблока "Участники".